# Background worker runs doWork multiple times

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

```
private void button_uploadToPI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        this.newFilePath = this.textbox_input_filePath.Text;
        this.label_status.Content = "";
        if (bgWorker.IsBusy != true)
        {


            bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Click Event.

```
public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.progressBar.Minimum = 0;
        this.progressBar.Maximum = 100;

        this.bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        this.bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        this.bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        reader.IsOpen = false;

        this.bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
        this.bgWorker.ProgressChanged += bgWorker_ProgressChanged;
        this.bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }
```

Main window method.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private BackgroundWorker bgWorker;
```

bgWorker is initialized here.

```
void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.progressBar.Value = 0;
        this.label_progressPercentage.Content = "0%";
        reportTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

RunWorkComplete code

The main issue is, if i run the application once, it works as expected. If i then click again, it will execute the method twice, and if i was to click it again it would execute the method 3 times. The will increment every new click.

Can anyone see the main issue here?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code posted. Any chance you could post the event handlers for the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: i added the code for my runworkcomplete method.

Comment: With "I click it again", do you mean clicking the `button_uploadToPI` or showing the form itself again?

Comment: Sounds you're subscribing multiple times to the button click event without unsubscribing.

Comment: Create a new instance of worker on each click and put it inside the bgWorker field. When worker completes, nullify the field. Check if the field is null instead of checking the IsBusy property. ...and don't use BackgroundWorker at all.

Answer (score 5):

A sample I worked on against @galenus's suggestion. I had the same situation with background worker, clicking the do work button firing the dowork multiple times until I initialized the worker with the button.
Code block:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

namespace MouseClick
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.Handled = true; // Din't do anything 
            worker = new BackgroundWorker(); //stopped the dowork being executed multiple times when button pressed again in the same session
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {


            int tot = 1;

            MessageBox.Show(tot.ToString()); //if this message box appears multiple times, it means the dowork is executing multiple times

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Running Number");

            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300799/cancel-background-worker-exception-in-e-result
                    //  e.Cancel = true; //This does the trick
                    e.Result = 100;
                    return;
                }
                worker.ReportProgress(i);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                dt.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            e.Result = dt;
        }

        #region "worker_ProgressChanged"
        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region "worker_RunWorkerCompleted"
        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            myGrid.ItemsSource = ((DataTable)e.Result).DefaultView;
            worker.Dispose();

        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this cause any memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

Though this probably works, you could have declared and initialized worker in the constructor of the MainWindow, after that you could also attach events. This way in your Button_Click method you need no more than run the worker. there is no need to create a new worker and attach these events each time button is clicked, you could save some time ;)

Answer (score -1):

@M00 gave the correct answer. You have to define DoWork and RunworkerCompleted once. I wrote an example, you can check it out.

```
    BackgroundWorker TaraBW = new BackgroundWorker();   

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TaraBW.DoWork += Tara;
        TaraBW.RunWorkerCompleted += TaraSon;
    }
    
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //If you write it here "DoWork" and "RunworkerCompleted",will branching occurs.
        TaraBW.RunWorkerAsync();
        
    }
    private void Tara(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\3dPC.xyz");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
        {
            SW.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(j + " " + j + 1 + " " + j + 2));
        }
        SW.Close();

    }

    private void TaraSon(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finish");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of sharing this information as a new answer, edit the existing answer to include this example.